# Spring security authentication manager exception

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

If I understand good, I have custom Authentication Manager class, and in there I check if someone in api pass correct credentials, but I wonder why it didn't throw exception while I passed empty username and password.

```
@Component
public class AuthManager implements AuthenticationManager {
    private final DetailsService detailsService;
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthManager.class);

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        logger.info("credentials: " + authentication.getCredentials());
        logger.info("principals: " + authentication.getPrincipal());
        if (authentication.getCredentials() == null || authentication.getPrincipal() == null) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Credentials are wrong");
        }
        UserDetails user = loadUser(authentication);
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUsername(), null, user.getAuthorities());
    }

    private UserDetails loadUser(Authentication auth) {
        return detailsService.loadUserByUsername(auth.getPrincipal().toString());
    }
```

That's filter

```
@Component
public class UsernamePasswordJsonFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    public UsernamePasswordJsonFilter(ObjectMapper objectMapper, AuthManager manager,
                                      AuthSuccessHandler success, AuthFailureHandler failure) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
        setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(success);
        setAuthenticationFailureHandler(failure);
        setAuthenticationManager(manager);
        setFilterProcessesUrl("/login");
    }


    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        try {
            LoginDTO authenticationRequest = objectMapper.readValue(request.getInputStream(), LoginDTO.class);
            Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authenticationRequest.getUsername(),
                    authenticationRequest.getPassword());
            logger.info("UsernamePasswordJsonFilter");
            return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(auth);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

[image]

If I pass correct username and password it works, but I just wonder why it didn't throw exception when credentials are empty, also there is no exception thrown in console, in case someone asks for it

Comment: Empty is not the same as `null`. Besides that, `authentication.getCredentials().equals(null)` is not correct since it will never reach that point. You can check with `==`, never with `.equals()`, a NPE will be raised before

Comment: @LeonardoEmmanueldeAzevedo I edited it, but anyway I can't figure out why it don't throw exception

Comment: You are checking for `null` and the values you are passing are empty. Do `if (authentication.getCredentials() == null || authentication.getPrincipal().isEmpty())`

Answer (score 0):

1. When you use
               `LoginDTO authenticationRequest = objectMapper.readValue(request.getInputStream(), LoginDTO.class);`
   It return `LoginDTO` with `login` = `""` and `password` = `""`. It is not a `null`.
   `""` is not the same as  `null`. If u want to be null in `LoginDTO`, request should not have `username` or `password` field at all
2. 

```
if (authentication.getCredentials() == null || authentication.getPrincipal() == null)
```

Here you also to check to empty string. Let's say  `"".equals(authentication.getCredentials())` or `authentication.getCredentials().isEmpty()`
same with `authentication.getPrincipal()`